# Can we find the closed-form solution to this optimization problem?

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, chi-squared

I have a simple optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\max\limits_{k}\overline{Q}_{k}^{-1}(10^{-3})-k^2\\
s.t. k>0
\end{equation}
where $\overline{Q}_{k}(b)$ is the complementary CDF of the chi-square random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom, evaluated at b, and $\overline{Q}_{k}^{-1}(b)$ denotes the inverse function of $\overline{Q}_{k}(b)$.

Let $f(k)=\overline{Q}_{k}^{-1}(10^{-3})-k^2$.

Intuitively, to find the optimal $k$, we need the derivative of $f(k)$ w.r.t. $k$.

However, the CDF of the chi-square random variable involves the [Incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
Then, I find it challenging to obtain the derivative of $f(k)$ w.r.t. $k$.

In fact, I even can not write $f(k)$ as a closed-form expression w.r.t. $k$.

I plot the simple function $f(k)$ using matlab, it is shown as:
[image]

So, the problem is: can we obtain the closed-form solution of the optimization problem?

---

I also need to obtain the optimization result when $b\neq 10^{-3}$.
So, here I just give a special case of my problem, and I want someone can give me help or suggestions.

Thanks!